# C# Listview - error provider on listview

Tags: c#, listview

can anyone please let me know is it possible to show error provider icon on listview.
ie if Im having a listview of items.. I would like to show error icon on a specific item in a row.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, or ASP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd solve this problem by changing the icon to an error (red circle with white cross) and adding a tooltip to the ListViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your images in the listview use ImageList class and bind it to the listview via SetImagelist method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a freeware WinForms component [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express). It allows displaying images of arbitrary size in both items and sub-items. You can also draw your own graphics with powerful owner drawing.

For example, all items can be shifted and you can display the ErrorProvider icon next to the items, or after them. Overlay is also possible.